# How do I extend an object definition within a class?

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript, ecmascript-6

The problem: I want to extend a class by adding additional properties to an object defined within it. Here's the scenario:

I have the following class defined:

```
export class SiteProperties {
     properties : {
         name: string;
     }
}
```

I use this class as a building block for the following class

```
export class Site extends SiteProperties {
     parent : SiteProperties[];
     online: number;
     issues: number;
}
```

The issue is that I want to extend SiteProperties to include additional fields within the 'properties' object so that it becomes:

```
export class SitePropertiesDetails { 
    properties : {
       name: string,
       description: string    // I basically want to add this field by extending the first SiteProperties class I created
   }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to avoid repeating the `name` properties inside of the last `SitePropertiesDetails` class by somehow extending the original `SiteProperties` class?

Comment: Is there a reason that you have the `properties` object within the classes, rather than just making the members of that `properties` object members of the class instead?

Comment: You'd have to give that currently anonymous object its own class (`SitePropertiesProperties`?) so that you can inherit from that.

Answer (score 1):

As [James Monger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916362/james-monger) points out, maybe this isn't the way to go?

If it is what you want, then you can use interfaces with optional parameters to define you `properties` object:

```js
interface ISiteProperties {
 parent?: SiteProperties[];
 online?: number;
 issues?: number;
 name?: string;
 description?: string;
}

class SiteProperties {
 public properties: ISiteProperties = {};
 constructor() {
  this.properties.name = "Test name";
 }
}

class Site extends SiteProperties {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.properties.online = 123;
  this.properties.issues = 321;
 }
}


var obj1 = new SiteProperties(), obj2 = new Site();

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

And the javascript version:

```js
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var SiteProperties = (function () {
    function SiteProperties() {
        this.properties = {};
        this.properties.name = "Test name";
    }
    return SiteProperties;
}());
var Site = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Site, _super);
    function Site() {
        _super.call(this);
        this.properties.online = 123;
        this.properties.issues = 321;
    }
    return Site;
}(SiteProperties));
var obj1 = new SiteProperties(), obj2 = new Site();
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the best OOP way to do this would be to have the properties on the class itself, rather than in an anonymous object.

```
export class SiteProperties {
    name: string;
}

export class Site extends SiteProperties {
    parent: SiteProperties[];
    online: number;
    issues: number;
}

export class SitePropertiesDetails extends SiteProperties { 
    description: string;
}

let x = new SitePropertiesDetails();
x.name = "Site Number One";
x.description = "The best site there is!";
```

As you can see, `SitePropertiesDetails` has both `name` and `description`. Does this meet your needs?